# What Structure Is Needed For Static Content Secondary Pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have 6 product pages. One of those product pages will have 6 secondary pages.

How would I create the controller for this so I end up with clean links.

```
/Products/Product1
/Products/Product2
/Products/Product3
/Products/Product4
/Products/Product5
/Products/Product6
/Products/Product6/SecondaryPage1
/Products/Product6/SecondaryPage2
/Products/Product6/SecondaryPage3
/Products/Product6/SecondaryPage4
/Products/Product6/SecondaryPage5
/Products/Product6/SecondaryPage6
```

I have looked into areas and can accomplish what I want with them but I haven't had any luck taking an area name and hyphenating it if underscores are present. I can get the controller and action to hyphenate but not areas. If someone knows how to get the area hyphenated I will go down that path again.

**More Info**

These are static content pages. There is no database involved. How would I setup a single controller to generate the URL's above? My issue has been with the secondary pages and how those are handled. Are areas the only way and if so how can I modify routing to allow a hyphen in the area name because I might have the need for that in the future?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do here. What do you mean by, "get the area hyphenated"? Are those URLs what you HAVE or what you WANT? What controllers/actions do you have and with what routes do you want to access them? You need to provide much more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't really make sense, especially given that the URLs you want don't contain any hyphens, but generally, the routes for an area are controlled by a file called `[AreaName]AreaRegistration.cs`. Inside the class in that file, there's the method:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "MyArea_default",
        "MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

So, you can easily change how the area is represented in the URL by changing this default route:

```
"My-Area/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```

(Notice the added hyphen. This is just a string and it can be made to look however you like. The area prefix in the URL doesn't have to match up to the actual area name.)